# Single or Multiple B2C Applications for API Access?

Tags: azure, api, azure-ad-b2c

We have multiple customers accessing our site via the Web and corporately via API calls.

We have a B2C environment setup and an Application setup within our B2C for the inbound API calls.

Is it best to share that B2C Application with all of our customers or to generate a custom B2C Application for each customer?

My thinking it would be ideal for each customer to have a different Application registration. If the customer closes their account, we just disable their Application and no further API calls can be made.

Is this correct?  Or does this present undue overhead?

Comment: Would you kindly Take a look. I hope you would get Idea from this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ,You want your customer to use your API and other feature that you want to let them access I guess for your business need [azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) is the good choice.

*But creating each application for each  user would not be the good idea think. It would be worth maintainable for you.*

What you could do is you may know B2C has many outstanding feature targeting your specific business need you could use that feature.

In your case, I would suggest you, Use [B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access) `Users` and `Groups` Policy. You can add your customer on each application that you like to. You could even create `Group` for that and you could assign a common rule you feel. You could govern access to protected resources [configuring scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application#configure-scopes) of your API, Even you could share [API access permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application#grant-permissions) on each group and user.

B2C has also [`User Policy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies) you  could customize your customer `signin` and `signup`policy as you want.

I think this would be easily maintainable for you. Once the customer no longer exist you could disable them or delete them.

> **Note:** If you have few customer only then you could create single 
>    application for each customer.

If you have any more query feel free to share. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: We have the customer base accessing our stuff via SSO and rhey can submit files. Our SSO customers can have files submitted in bul. I assume this will be a headless connection with no user interaction. It is this account that I was asking the question about.

Comment: Yeah I got to know.

Comment: As it turns out the primary API customer wint send files in a headless situation. So I will do an Azure AD application for each customer. Seems the right way to go. Original question was related to a single account vs multiple accounts.